# Redirect if user uses IP and not (Sub)Domain

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, redirect

I have an Apache server and I want to redirect every user that is connecting to my Website if they don't use a specific Domain, in this case a subdomain.
So if I use the IP I want to get redirected to somewhere else and if I use a specific Domain i want to get Access to my Website.

I already found `VirtualHost`s but all I googled was not helpful.
Do I have to create a new file in `sites-available`?

So i created the file and named it redirect. If i open my Website now i get redirected but it should show me the correct website. What did i wrong?
Here the content of my files:

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerName www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**redirect.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://www.examplesubdomain.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, I recommend that you have two sites in `sites-available`.

Once you have initially installed Apache, you can expect to find a default site having been created automatically. The name of the file might vary between distributions. On Ubuntu systems it is `000-default.conf`.

In this `VirtualHost` you can simply use `Redirect` to redirect all users to a real domain name.

Additionally you need to create another file with your real site. In this `VirtualHost` you need to use `ServerName` to specify the domain name you expect users to be using.

Any user using the domain name in the second file will be served by that `VirtualHost`. Everybody else will be served by the default `VirtualHost` which simply redirects.

The reason it doesn't work with the sites as written in your question is, that you got the syntax of `ServerName` wrong. Remove `http://` and it should work.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this, but now i a scenario that i can not explain. Maybe it is, because i redirect from an other System. To Explain it: i created an .htacces on an hosted Webspace that redirects to my own System with `Redirect 301 / http://myip/Subdir`. If i open the link to the hosted site it shows me an Server not Found Error, because the adress the browser is trying to open is `http://example.comexample`. The redirection to me Site when only the IP is browsed works great!

Comment: @DERYANNEK What is the domain name?

Comment: You can have a look at this if you open http://multicraft.pixlbox.net it redirects to http://pixlbox.netmulticraft but i want to redirect to http://94.23.0.149/multicraft

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use dynamic hosts (in 000-default.conf):

```
# First, www.* config
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias www.*
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2+

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    UseCanonicalName    Off

    <Directory /var/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Then, * config
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    UseCanonicalName    Off

    <Directory /var/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This way, you simply create all (sub)domain folders in /var/www and Apache will serve the files based on URL requested. Just create folder named as your IP and it will work.
Two VirtualHosts are used to avoid having to create www.* symlink for each domain (where you serve www.* content).

Comment: This may be useful in some situations, but it doesn't really do what is being asked for in the question.

Comment: @kasperd He said: "So if I use the IP I want to get redirected to somewhere else and if I use a specific Domain i want to get Access to my Website."

This **will** do the job - he can do the redirect to "somewhere else" with .htaccess or something else inside _server.ip_ folder when using configuration I provided.

Comment: You did not explain that in your answer. Besides if a separate directory is required for every single value a client could plausibly send in the `Host` header, then that's going to be a lot of directories.